# Direct conversion of base 36 to base 16?

Tags: math

Describe a process to convert a base36 number to base16, without converting to base10 as an intermediary.

Comment: I can assure you it's not.  I've converted a sha256 hash (256 bit digest in hex) to a base36 value for storing in db. But I need a way to convert back to base16 for comparison.  I know how to do it with a decimal intermediary, but it's not very elegant and i'd like something cleaner.

Comment: I would appreciate if you would remove the negative point.  I don't think thats merited.

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal intermediary"?

Comment: Are you sure it's not base 2 that you're using as an intermediary? Because that's the most likely scenario, and the easiest.

Comment: Conversion from base-36 to base-10 and then converting from base-10 to base-16. But there is really no difference between the various bases; conversion always works the same.

Comment: You're only likely to convert to base 10 if you are doing it by pencil and paper. If you are using a computer then you just use an integer register. There is no "base 10" there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a function `f` for converting a single base-36-digit to base-16, you can define your conversion function `c` recursively as follows: For a base-36 number with digits `a_n ... a_1` with `n > 1` return `f(a_1) + 24_16*c(a_n ... a_2)` (as 36 is represented as "24" in base-16); for a base-36 number `a_1` with only one digit just return `f(a_1)`. This obviously assumes you are able to do arithmetic in base-16.

Of course, the real problem here is doing arithmetic in base-16 -- which is why you usually do base conversions via some intermediary base you can do arithmetic in; i.e. base-10 on paper and base-2 in the computer.

Note that converting from base-2 to base-16 is a very easy operation. As 16 is a power of 2,  you don't need to perform any arithmetic: You can perform the transformation digit by digit (or rather, 4-digits by 4-digits).

Comment: I guess I don't understand this since I can't see how this would work.

Comment: What do you not understand about this?

Comment: I share the confusion.  629 is 'hh' in base 36 (with standard digits+letters mapping), and '275' in base 16.  'h' = 17, however, is '11' in base 16.  No recursive accumulation-of-digits approach can work here.  It looks to me like you simply mean "integer" instead of "base-16 [collection of digits]".

Comment: My approach doesn't do "accumulation-of-digits" in base-16, but requires you to do arithmetic in base_16. I.e. in your example: `c(hh) = f(h) + 24_16*c(h) = 11_16 + 24_16*11_16 = 275_16 = 629`. Of course, the real problem here is doing arithmetic in base-16 -- which is why you usually do base conversions via some intermediary base you can do arithmetic in; i.e. base-10 on paper and base-2 in the computer.

Comment: Ok, I think I see it now.  Unless I can perform arithmetic on a base other than 10, I will have to convert to base10 first.  Seems theres no way going around it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you CAN do this directly, but you need to do arithmetic in base 16. The trick is to precompute the value of 36, 36^2, 36^3, etc., in base 16. For example, convert the number represented as 237 in base 36, into a number in base 16.

A simple approach is to to do the conversion into decimal, or any intermediate system where you can do arithmetic. Thus I might do it as

2*36^2 + 3*36 + 7 = 2707 (decimal)

Then convert to hex from decimal, yielding

10*16^2 + 9*16 + 3 = A93 (hex)

The direct solution is easy enough. I've done it that way to convince you that it was not necessary. Simply compute (in advance) the value of 36^2 in hex. Thus,

36^2 = 510 (hex)

36 = 24 (hex)

Store these precomputed values away. Now do all of your computations in hex.

237 (base 36) = 2*510 + 3*24 + 7 (hex)

Do that last expansion in hex arithmetic, and you should get A93 in hex. You have done the computation as desired entirely in hex, without resorting to an intermediate base. Even the precomputation of those powers of 36 can be done in hex.